# Print time to end (decremental) in drawtext in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to figure how to use ffmpeg drawtext function, which prints overlays over video where will be time remains to end of video file.

Seems it's not problem to do it from start (00:00:00) using `%{pts\:hms}` where time counting from start to end of video file, but how to do the same from end of video file to start (it starts counting from 00:02:00 to 00:00:00 for 2min video)?

Comment: I found another option by using a color with transparent background, drawtext, reverse filter and overlay: https://superuser.com/a/1826696/137093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options, both of which require knowing the exact video duration.

1. if a simple count-down timer in seconds is enough then you can simply do

   ```
   text='%{eif\:$duration-t\:d}'
   ```

   like in [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/ffmpeg-video-with-timer) which is coincidentally found on the proper forum for this kind of questions.
2. if you need a fancier timer, ie. HMS, then dynamically generate a subtitle file in a format such as `ASS` and [burn it in](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo).

Comment: Awesome!! I was looking for this several days and was not able to find. May I didn't use correct search terms. Thank you!

Comment: The code example, is it for Linux? How do I write it in a Windows batch file?

Comment: @Arete `duration` is the variable to be expanded so replace `$duration` with the Windows equivalent (`%duration%`? it's been a while...). You have to set the value before executing the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Thanks, that was the only part I actually did understand, but what about the rest? I made a separate question here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/26036/translate-ffmpeg-drawtext-bash-code-to-batch